# 503 Service Unavailable error in all pages except added to my route file

Tags: 8, routes

I have a D8 web with some views and pages. If I log in with administrator user, all works good. If I log in with a normal user, I get `503 service unavailable` error after some seconds of load. It happens with all pages (view pages, public pages, etc.), and I can only open pages (routes) that were defined in my module. Anonymous user can navigate to public pages but normal users can't navigate to those pages after log in.
It looks like a problem with permissions, but I have rebuild it with success. Some suggestion?

EDITED:

As requested I added my route file. But thouse paths work good. The problem is with other paths. The most weird are public pages that get error when you are logged in, but not if you are anonymous user. Except for administrator.

```
licencias_pesca.copiarmodalidades:
  path: '/copiarmodalidades'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\licencias_pesca\Form\CopiarModalidadesForm'
    _title: 'Copiar modalidades por categorias'
  requirements:
    _role: 'gestion+administrator'

licencias_pesca.crearliquidacionprevia:
  path: '/crearliquidacionprevia'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\licencias_pesca\Form\CrearLiquidacionPreviaForm'
    _title: 'Formulario previo para crear una liquidacion'
  requirements:
    _role: 'club+gestion+administrator'
```

Comment: Post your route code.

Comment: Looks like your server is in kind of an endless redirect loop. Can you post the complete reponse header? And maybe post your module.routing.yml. Did you change the 403 and/or 404 settings in site.settings?

Comment: I have added my route file. I didn't change the site.settings. The response header is: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2019 08:09:29 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 428
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Is that the proper format for the role requirement?

Comment: Yes. It is OR clause (+). But as I said, thouse routes work good.

Comment: I don’t understand how adding these routes would disable the rest of the site. If you disable this module does everything else work again?

Comment: I have found the problem. I have a node_grants hook and It works good with a few nodes. When I've loaded thousands of nodes, It dies in a very slow loop. Thanks for your help.